# I am unable to make REST api calls on a specific url in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

i am unable to make a simple get call on this URL >>>

```
http://54.254.255.202:8080/user/status/S5454523D/ST.
```

This url working good on any thing other that flutter like postman, chrome, android or react-native. I specifically dont know the reason it works only in 1 out of 20 tries. In the logs I get something like this

```
E/flutter: [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
Connection closed before full header was received
```

Also here is the code that I am using to try this simple get request

```
Future<dynamic> getStatus() async {
var res;
String url = "http://54.254.255.202:8080/user/status/S5454523D/ST";
print(url);
var response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull(url),
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
    ).catchError((error){
      print(error);
}).whenComplete((){
  print("completed");
});
print(response);
return res;
}
```

Any other URL I am using is working good.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simplifying your `getStatus` method. This version seems to reliably return the decoded json.

```
Future<Map> getStatus() async {
  try {
    Response r = await http.get(
      'http://54.254.255.202:8080/user/status/S5454523D/ST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    );
    return json.decode(r.body);
  } catch (e) {
    return {'error': e.toString()};
  }
}

main() async {
  print(await getStatus());
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer, I am still getting the same message...Connection closed before full header was received... Were you able to get response with your method.?

Comment: Try running it just as a pure Dart program (if you haven't done so already, download the Dart SDK separately). I've run it several times with 100% success.

Answer (score 0):

I spend some time over that and the thing was that it worked with postman and it worked the call from the production endpoint.
The problem was that i was connected to different WIFIs from